# Table - number of columns

Tags: tables

What mistakes are here please? I would like to have 8 colums in the table. Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}        % rozšíření pro sazbu matematiky
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % matematické fonty
\usepackage{bm}             % tučné symboly (příkaz \bm)
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % zajistí přidání seznamu literatury,
\usepackage{icomma}         % inteligetní čárka v matematickém módu
\usepackage{dcolumn}        % lepší zarovnání sloupců v tabulkách
\usepackage{booktabs}       % lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách

\newcommand{\pulrad}[1]{\raisebox{1.5ex}[0pt]{#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}



\begin{table}[b!]

\centering

\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1.5cm}}D{.}{,}{3.2}D{.}{,}{1.2}D{.}{,}{2.3}D{.}{,}{3.2}D{.}{,}{3.2}D{.}{,}{3.2}D{.}{,}{3.2}}

\toprule
 & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{}  \\
\pulrad{\textbf{Způsob měření}} & \mc{\pulrad{$\bm{P_{\mathrm{siderická}}}$}} & \mc{\pulrad{$\bm{e}$}} &
\mc{\pulrad{$\bm{T_{\mathrm{periastr.}} \ \left({\rm RJD}\right)}$}} & \mc{\pulrad{$\bm{\omega \rm \left(^\circ\right)}$}} & \mc{\pulrad{$\bm{K_1}\rm \left({\rm km\rm s^{-1}}\right)}$}} & \mc{\pulrad{$\bm{V_{\gamma}\rm \left({\rm km\rm s^{-1}}\right)}$}} & Zdroj \\
\midrule
& & & & & & & \\

\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{Pozn:}
$^a$ Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**
How to write longer number to colums? Are multicolums connected to rows below?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % choose suitable text block parameters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{icomma,dcolumn,booktabs} 

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} % new
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L d{3.2} d{1.2} d{2.3} d{2.3} *{4}{d{3.2}} @{}}
\toprule
Zdroj & 
\mc{$P$} & 
\mc{$T_0$}  & 
\mc{$e$} &
\mc{$\omega$} & 
\mc{$i$} & 
\mc{$a$} & 
\mc{$a$} &

\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$M_1$} \\[0.33ex]
  & \mc{(dny)}
  & \mc{(RJD)}
  & \mc{} 
  & \mc{($ {\rm ^\circ}$)} 
  & \mc{($ {\rm ^\circ}$)}
  & \mc{($ {\rm R_{\odot}}$)} 
  & \mc{($ {\rm M_{\odot}}$)} 
  & \mc{($ {\rm M_{\odot}}$)}   
  \\
\midrule

1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46) & 12.345 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 &\\

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{\footnotesize\textit{Pozn:} $^a$ Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without testing, just looking ... there seems to be a closing brace missing after *Pozn:*

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes. E.g., the first three instances of `D{.}{,}{3.2}}` -- but not the final one -- should be `D{.}{,}{3.2}`. The macro `\mc` isn't defined. The macro `\pulrad` isn't defined. You shouldn't be using `\rm`. Several closing braces are either misplaced or missing.

Comment: Not quite. Use an editor that gives you proper code markup and bracket matching. Your tabular definition has several double closing braces. Apart from that, your code produces several undefined cs errors. Please be more careful in preparing your questions. And please finally read that introduction I guided you to read.

Comment: Thank you, I repaired some of mitakes. For expample I have error in this:
'\mc{\pulrad{$\bm{T_{\mathrm{periastr.}} \ \left({\rm RJD}\right)}$}}' and I really can't see where is a problem?

Comment: Your edit has removed some errors, but it has also introduced *new syntax errors*.

Comment: What are syntax errors?

Comment: What's a syntax error? There are many possible types of syntax errors. Among the most basic ones are omitting curly braces or supplying too many of them. Not knowing how `pulrad` and `\mc` are defined, it's also possible that syntax errors lurk in the definitions of these two macros.

Comment: And to braces: \mc{\pulrad{$\bm{T_{\mathrm{periastr.}} \ \left({\rm RJD}\right)}$}}
Where is here wrong please? I checked it many times I can't see it.

Comment: I eddited question for more elementary step.

Comment: @Elisabeth: You still did not provide the definitions of `\mc` and `\pulrad`.

Comment: I have got it defined, but I can't find where. I added picture of errors in documets structure. There are mistakes in braces.

Comment: @Elisabeth: Without knowing the definition of the above mentioned macros, it is impossible for others to correct the errors in your code as they might be hidden in the definition of the macros. In order to find the definitions in your code, you might want to search for `\newcommand{\mc}`. Please also test your example codes before posting them. Your example does not match the screenshot of the errors you posted.

Comment: I am sorry editted it.

Comment: (-1) The first thing I remark is that your code is **not** compilable. Please add a code which is compilable, in that case you will get much more help.

Comment: When I copy the code now, I can compile it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to fixing various syntax errors (such as missing, surplus, or misplaced curly braces), the following solution attempts to make the table more readable by (a) placing the units of measurement information on a separate, subordinated line, (b) not using **bold** anywhere, and (c) using the `\si` macro (provided by the `siunitx` package) to typeset the units according to recognized standards. The solution also employs a `tabularx` environment instead of the basic `tabular` environment. That way, you can assure that the material will fit inside the width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % choose suitable text block parameters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{icomma,dcolumn,booktabs} 

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,ragged2e} % new
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L d{3.2} d{1.2} d{2.3} *{4}{d{3.2}} @{}}
\toprule
%& \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{}  \\
Způsob měření & 
\mc{$P_{\textrm{siderická}}$} & 
\mc{$e$} &
\mc{$T_{\textrm{periastr.}}$}  & 
\mc{$\omega$} & 
\mc{$K_1$} & 
\mc{$V_{\gamma}$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Zdroj} \\[0.33ex]
&&& \mc{(RJD)} 
  & \mc{(\si{\degree\kelvin})} % or, "\celsius" (?)
  & \mc{(\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})}
  & \mc{(\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})} \\
\midrule
\dots & 123.45 & 1.23 & 12.345 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 \\

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{\footnotesize\textit{Pozn:} $^a$ Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have still problem with siunitx - undefined control sequence. I have installed siunitx.

Comment: @Elisabeth - please be a lot more specific. E.g., *which control sequence* is undefined?

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/FRlP5.png it is again this - there is not 228 line. I have restart my computer but it didn't halp.

Comment: @Elisabeth - It sounds like you really should fully update your MikTeX distribution.

Comment: I have only MikTex package manager, but I have no Console.

Comment: @Elisabeth - A high priority to-do item for you should be to learn how to set up and install a properly functioning MikTeX distribution. You can search this site for advice on how to do this.

Comment: I found that it is possible in MikTeX Console - there is an update. To be honest I am afraid of installing something, I am scared that it will stop working. LaTeX work fine until doing this table.

Comment: No no, thank you for you answer, I use it when I solve this problem.

Comment: `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}`

`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L d{3.2} d{1.2} d{2.3} *{4}{d{3.2}} @{}}P`
Please can you explain to me this?
I understand only to first {}
How to set the width of space between first and second colum?

Comment: @Elisabeth - `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}` defines a column with label `d`; it serves, essentially, as a shorthand device, so that one can write `d{3.2}` instead of the far more cumbersome `D{.}{,}{3.2}`. The particle `*{4}{d{3.2}}` means: "4 columns of type `d{3.2}`. The `@{}` particles serve to suppress whitespace padding at the edges of the `tabularx` environment`. The `L` column type is a left-aligned version of the `X` column type provided by the `tabularx` package.  I have no idea what `P` is supposed to do. I would *not* set an extra-wide space between columns 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you and how can I  do this like previous ones - to center it? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItQyc.png
`\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Zdroj} \\[0.33ex]`

Answer (score 4):

In the following code, I have removed the superflouous `}` that prevented the code from compiling. I have also removed the bold in the table, as it might be too distracting. Additionally, I have added the `siunitx` packages for consistant representation of units. Lastly, I have used `\addlinespace` to add more vertical white space around the table entries instrad of the `\pulrad` command.

However, please note, that your table is too wide to fit onto the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}        % rozšíření pro sazbu matematiky
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % matematické fonty
\usepackage{bm}             % tučné symboly (příkaz \bm)
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % zajistí přidání seznamu literatury,
\usepackage{icomma}         % inteligetní čárka v matematickém módu
\usepackage{dcolumn}        % lepší zarovnání sloupců v tabulkách
\usepackage{booktabs}       % lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}


\begin{document}



\begin{table}[b!]

\centering

\begin{tabular}{lD{.}{,}{3.2}D{.}{,}{1.2}D{.}{,}{2.3}D{.}{,}{3.2}D{.}{,}{3.2}D{.}{,}{3.2}D{.}{,}{3.2}}

\toprule \addlinespace
Způsob měření & 
\mc{$P_{\mathrm{siderická}}$} & 
\mc{$e$} &
\mc{$T_{periastr.}  \left({ RJD}\right)$} & 
\mc{$\omega$ (\si{\degree})  } & 
\mc{$K_1$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})} & 
\mc{$V_{\gamma}$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})} & 
\mc{Zdroj} \\ \addlinespace
\midrule
& & & & & & & \\

\bottomrule

\multicolumn{8}{p{\textwidth}}{\footnotesize \textit{Pozn:} \textsuperscript{a} Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabular}


\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and what does this errors mean? 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRlP5.png

Comment: @elisabeth probably that a package is outdated. Maybe something else. Please learn how to properly read the log file and copy the error messages. A screenshot of the thing your editor already garbled up isnt very helpful.

Comment: Where is log life plese? I have only .lot, .log. .aux

Comment: the log file is the one with `.log` at the end...

Comment: I am sorry I wanted to write lof instead of log in previous command. I can't find log.

Comment: @Elisabeth Free ebook to learn the basics -> https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/ It is worth a read ;-)